# "element is not attached to the page document" error while using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to print the values of 5 different options in 5 different texfiles, so i have been trying to use the below code:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('url');
time.sleep(3)


ele=driver.find_element_by_id("reportDate")
ele.clear()
ele.send_keys("21-Nov-2015")


currency = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='currencyCode']")
options = currency.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
optionsList = []

for option in options: #iterate over the options, place the attribute value in list
 optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))
 for optionValue in optionsList:
  print "starting loop on option %s" % optionValue
  driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('currencyCode').style.display = 'block';")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='currencyCode']/option[@value='"+optionValue+"']").click()


  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=\"submit"]').click()
  time.sleep(5)


  infile="ice."+optionValue+"."+x+".txt"
  with open(infile,"w") as ice_content:
   data=[]
   for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="table table-responsive table-data"]//tr'):
    tds=tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    if tds:
     data=([td.text for td in tds])
     ice_content.write(str("|".join(data))+"\n")
```

after printing the first textfile, it throws me the error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Below is the html snippet:

```
<label for="currencyCode">Currency</label>
<select id="currencyCode" name="criteria.currencyCode" class="form-control" style="display: none;">
                <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
                <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
                <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
                <option value="USD">USD</option>
            </select>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 297px;" title="" id="currencyCode_chosen">
```

DO tell me as to where i am going wrong, Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

Comment: i am sorry, but i cant seem to find the solution from the above url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to find the `currencyCode` object by xpath, you can just do it by ID like you did before like `currency = driver.find_element_by_id("currencyCode")`

Can you at least give a line number where the assertion is happening as there's a few places the exception could be throwing.

Comment: found the solution, i have to open the text file before the second for loop. That gave me the answer

Answer (score -1):

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('url');
time.sleep(3)


ele=driver.find_element_by_id("reportDate")
ele.clear()
ele.send_keys("21-Nov-2015")


currency = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='currencyCode']")
options = currency.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
optionsList = []

for option in options: #iterate over the options, place the attribute value in list
 optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))
for optionValue in optionsList:
  print "starting loop on option %s" % optionValue
  infile="ice."+optionValue+"."+x+".txt"
  with open(infile,"w") as ice_content:
   driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('currencyCode').style.display = 'block';")
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='currencyCode']/option[@value='"+optionValue+"']").click()


   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=\"submit"]').click()
   time.sleep(5)

   data=[]
   for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="table table-responsive table-data"]//tr'):
     tds=tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
     if tds:
      data=([td.text for td in tds])
      ice_content.write(str("|".join(data))+"\n")
```